# Windows IoT on RPI Unique Identifier

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, iot

I am currently searching for a solution to get 2 unique strings on the RPI with Windows IoT. The strings should not change after reboot. It should be something like an Hardware ID to identify a device.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the MAC address of your nework card, which should Uniquely identify it every single time.

```
var macAddr = 
    (
        from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
        select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```